# Basic Java Sprite Animation

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedimage

```
private BufferedImage water1;
BufferedImage[] waterAnim = new BufferedImage[1];
waterAnim[0] = water1;
```

This bit of code yields an error expecting "{" and "}". Any thoughts as to how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you just write all of that in the class directly? Or did you write a method for the second and third lines?

Comment: Oh, I have to write a method for the second and third lines? Can you explain how and/or show an example?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, fields and methods are declared within classes, while code that needs to be executed goes in methods.

```
public class SomeClass {
    private BufferedImage water1;

    public void loadImage() { /* you may need to return something else */
        BufferedImage[] waterAnim = new BufferedImage[1];
        waterAnim[0] = water1;
        /* do other stuff */
   }
}
```

Then you would call that method from somewhere else (e.g. your project's `main()`) after you initialize that object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass(); /* object initialization */
        someObject.loadImage(); /* calling that method */
}
```

I recommend reading up on Java and object oriented programming in general.